# Corners not rounding for button in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to round a button's bottom corners by calling this method in `layoutSubviews` for a `UITableViewCell`:

```
func styleRescueButton() {
    let rescueButtonCornerLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let rescueButtonRoundedCornersPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rescueNowButton.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.bottomLeft, UIRectCorner.bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: MyTheme.cornerRadius, height: MyTheme.cornerRadius))
    rescueButtonCornerLayer.path = rescueButtonRoundedCornersPath.cgPath
    rescueNowButton.layer.mask = rescueButtonCornerLayer
    rescueNowButton.clipsToBounds = true
    rescueNowButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

it's not working at all though, the corners are not rounding. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why aren't you using "rescueNowButton.layer.cornerRadius = rescueNowButton.frame.size.height/2" for rounded corners?

Comment: It's just part of my theme. `MyTheme.cornerRadius = 4.0`. If I change it to what you suggested it doesn't work either.

Comment: `rescueNowButton.layer.cornerRaidus = 5.0; rescueNowButton.layer.masksToBounds = true` is enough to get button corner rouding. Remove other codes, and try again.

Comment: I want to round only the bottom two corner @Enix

Comment: how is your table view cell being initialised? with xib or programmatically? I have tested to run the corner round code in table view cell `layoutSubViews`, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Enix via a xib

Answer (score 1):

You can define an extension:

```
extension UIButton{
func bottomRoundButton(){
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners [.BottomLeft , .BottomRight], cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

You can do the same things for other corner as well. Just change `byRoundingCorners [.BottomLeft , .BottomRight]`

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you never set mask's frame. Also it's not necessary to set `clipsToBounds` and `layer.masksToBounds`:

These lines can be removed:

```
rescueNowButton.clipsToBounds = true
rescueNowButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

**Working function in Swift 3:**

```
func styleRescueButton() {
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = rescueNowButton.bounds
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(
        roundedRect: rescueNowButton.bounds,
        byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight],
        cornerRadii: CGSize(width:  MyTheme.cornerRadius, height:  MyTheme.cornerRadius)).cgPath
    rescueNowButton.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Comment: Tried this and still nothing. I wonder if the views have not been setup in time to apply the mask..currently calling this code in `layoutSubviews`

Comment: oddly it works if I refresh the tableView..but the initial cell load doesn't

Comment: Try to override `awakeFromNib` and call `layoutIfNeeded()` and `styleRescueButton()` there

Comment: This will round the left corner only. The right button isn't rounded and it seems like the width of the button is a little shorter than it should be now too.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest to use Layers to make your button round.
You can use button.layer.cornerRadius , .layer.borderwidth to get your button  with rounded corner.